# An error occurred when trying to authenticate to the FCM servers. Make sure the credential used to authenticate this SDK

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, nestjs

An error occurred when trying to authenticate to the FCM servers. Make sure the credential used to authenticate this SDK has the proper permissions. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup for setup instructions.

Comment: This issue is slove it because of permission in firebase application the fire base has updated the permission so first we have to to firebase and set the permission the it will slove there is no issue in fcm Token